# python project - required packages won't install in pych

Tags: pandas, nltk, spacy, streamlit, pymysql

currently im bulinding resume analyzer application which is based on python,streamlit, xampp,and nlp
I'm getting the error in the terminal -
`OSError: [E050] Can't find model 'en_core_web_sm'.`   It doesn't seem to be a Python package or a valid path to a data directory.

```py
import streamlit as st
import nltk
import spacy
nltk.download('stopwords')
spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
```

For this project I'm using python 3.12 version and latest paycharm version.
I'm not able to get the expected output as the required packages cant install in pycharm.

Answer (score 0):

When you load the `en_core_web_sm` you need first to install it

```
python -m spacy download en_core_web_lg
```